# Angular - 404 when directly visiting localhost:8080/somePage, but OK on href link?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

Only after adding CRUD to my angular controller and service do I get a 404 error when I visit localhost:8080/somePage directly..

> Cannot GET /somePage

The href links in my navbar that point to the same URL are still working though!

```
<li><a href="/somePage">somePage</a></li>
```

**Some admin pages won't have page links though, so I need to get to them directly. Any suggestions?**

Going to look at the API directly via localhost:8080/api/stuff does display the json:

> [   {
>       "text": "item 1",
>       "done": false,
>       "*id": "53402c4390dfad962a000001",
>       "*_v": 0   } ]

Here's my appRoutes.js

```
angular.module('appRoutes', []).config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider

        // home page
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
            controller: 'mainController'
        })

        // 
        .when('/somePage', {
            templateUrl: 'views/somePage.html',
            controller: 'mainController'    
        });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

}]);
```

Here's the node+express server.js:

```
// set up ======================================================================
var express  = require('express');
var app      = express();                               // create our app w/ express
var mongoose = require('mongoose');                     // mongoose for mongodb
var port     = process.env.PORT || 8080;                // set the port
var database = require('./config/database');            // load the database config

// configuration ===============================================================
mongoose.connect(database.url);     // connect to mongoDB database on modulus.io

app.configure(function() {
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));         // set the static files location /public/img will be /img for users
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));                         // log every request to the console
    app.use(express.bodyParser());                          // pull information from html in POST
    app.use(express.methodOverride());                      // simulate DELETE and PUT
});

// routes ======================================================================
require('./app/routes.js')(app);    // load the routes

// listen (start app with node server.js) ======================================
app.listen(port);
console.log("App listening on port " + port);
```

And here's the Node.js routes.js, per Iqbal Fauzi's comment..

```
// load the stuff model
var Stuff = require('./models/stuff');

// expose the routes to our app with module.exports
module.exports = function(app) {

    // api ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    // get all the stuff
    app.get('/api/stuff', function(req, res) {

        // use mongoose to get all the stuff in the database
        Stuff.find(function(err, stuff) {

            // if there is an error retrieving, send the error. nothing after res.send(err) will execute
            if (err)
                res.send(err)

            res.json(stuff); // return all the stuff in JSON format
        });
    });

    // create stuff and send back all the stuff after creation
    app.post('/api/stuff', function(req, res) {

        // create stuff, information comes from AJAX request from Angular
        Stuff.create({
            text : req.body.text,
            done : false
        }, function(err, stuff) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            // get and return all the stuff after you create another
            Stuff.find(function(err, stuff) {
                if (err)
                    res.send(err)
                res.json(stuff);
            });
        });

    });

    // delete stuff
    app.delete('/api/stuff/:stuff_id', function(req, res) {
        Stuff.remove({
            _id : req.params.stuff_id
        }, function(err, stuff) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            // get and return all the stuff after you create another
            Stuff.find(function(err, stuff) {
                if (err)
                    res.send(err)
                res.json(stuff);
            });
        });
    });


    // application -------------------------------------------------------------
    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.sendfile('./public/index.html'); // load the single view file (angular will handle the page changes on the front-end)
    });

        // commented out for testing this problem.. because this otherwise redirects..
    // app.get('*', function (req, res) {
    //  res.redirect('/');  // redirect to / and index.html will be served
    // });

};
```

Comment: What happens if you visit `domain.com/#/somePage` ?

Comment: @TimWithers Something alters that to domain.com/#%2FsomePage.. Am on localHost right now though, so updated the post to reflect that. What I get is localHost:8080/#%2FsomePage

Comment: The problem is not on your AngularJS, it's on your node.js router, could you please put the node.js router?

Comment: @IqbalFauzi just added the router.js from the Node side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncomment your `app.get('*', function (req, res)` and instead of redirecting it to '/' you will better return the `index.html` file, let AngularJS handle the browser URL for you.

```
app.get('*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile('./public/index.html');
});
```